# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on compile

Tags: java, android, butterknife, dagger-2, retrolambda

I'm trying to compile an Android project unsuccessfully. The error message is:

> Execution failed for task ':mobile:_compileAppDebug'.
>
> > java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.auto.common.MoreTypes.asTypeElements(Ljavax/lang/model/util/Types;Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet;

Here are my module's gradle dependencies in which I specify a number of libraries including google Auto:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0-SNAPSHOT'
    provided 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.0-rc1'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0-SNAPSHOT'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28' 
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0' 
    compile 'com.f2prateek.dart:dart:1.1.0'
}
```

When I looked at the dependencies I thought I just needed google auto value since that is where the missing method resides but adding the provided does not resolve the issue.

The project gradle file includes the retrolambda plugin

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:2.5.0'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.+'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
}
```

Can anyone help me identify which dependencies cause the compile error? Interestingly enough, when I copy the gradle files into an empty project everything runs fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dagger 2.0-SNAPSHOT depends on an Auto SNAPSHOT which had an API change: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/113

This is perfectly normal and acceptable thing for libraries which are under development. If you cannot tolerate an occasional broken build, do not depend on non-release versions in a manner that can change at any time without warning.

Comment: first things first: we appreciate and use your stuff everywhere so thanks++ Just wanted to add, this isn't production ready work so there's no expectation of perfect library references, I just was beyond my depth in getting to the bottom of the issue. I will try the workarounds from the referenced issues page for now.

Comment: It's apparently fixed in the latest snapshot. Might need to remove dagger 2 from your gradle cache depending on your cache config.

Comment: It is fixed, yes. Alternatively, use `--refresh-dependencies` which is much less destructive.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in a similar issue. Some libary I'm using bundles Guava within the jar file.

Thus exluding this specific dependency from the apt configuration fixed the problem:

```
configurations {
  apt.exclude module: 'artifactId-Of-Library' 
}
```